# What's the technical name for the "additive cosets" of an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, each $g \in G$ yields a so-called (left) **coset** $gH$. I think something similar happens for the ideals of a unital ring $R$: if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $r\in R$, then $r + I$ would be an "additive coset".

Example. If $R$ is ${\mathbb Z}$ and $I$ is $4{\mathbb Z}$ and $r$ is 5, then $5 + 4{\mathbb Z}$ is one such "coset", and it ends up being an element of the quotient ring ${\mathbb Z} / 4{\mathbb Z}$.

Is there a technical name for subsets of $R$ of the form $r + I$ for some $r \in R$ and some ideal $I \subseteq R$?

Comment: Why not just use the term coset?

Comment: Try trying to see if it's a standard term =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coset is a perfectly good term to use. Note that $R$ is a group under addition, and an ideal $I$ is a subgroup of this group. Thus $r+I$ is in fact a coset in the usual sense.